# C++ delivering function name to macro and calling it

Tags: c++, function, macros

I have two classes. First class do some thing and then just call method of second class. Every method of first class do that. Is it possible to automate code implementation using some macro?

Example:

```
class A
{
  void Do1()
  {
   Do task x
   ClassB b;
   b.Do1();
   Do task y
  }
  void Do2()
  {
   Do task x
   ClassB b;
   b.Do2();
   Do task y
  }
}
```

Is it possible to implement this way? This doesn't work, but something similar.

```
#define VOID_FUNC(name) \
   Do task x;\
   ClassB b;\
   b.##name##();\
   Do task y;

class A
{
  void Do1()
  {
    VOID_FUNC(__FUNCTION__);
  }
  void Do2()
  {
    VOID_FUNC(__FUNCTION__);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably, but the cuter way would be to use templates, `std::bind`, and `std::function`. I'll be sure to upvote an answer that sketches this out.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an easy way to create what you are asking, and the not-so-easy ways get ugly real fast; it may help if you explain why you want to do this, since there may be a better way to accomplish your purpose?  It looks as though you want to write a wrapper around an existing class that manages some kind of resource that the class uses, where task x would acquire the resource, and task y would release it.  One idea that occurred to me is that the C++ Standard Library generally allows custom allocators that might actually be adaptable, even for things like logging.

Answer (score 2):

There are many good reasons to avoid macros, for one they don't respect namespaces.

Another solution is to use lambda functions (C++11 and later) when you want to reuse `task x` and `task y`:

```
class A
{
  template <typename Fun>
  void wrapClassB(Fun&& fun)
  {
   Do task x
   ClassB b;
   fun(b);
   Do task y
  }

  void Do1()
  {
   wrapClassB([] (ClassB& b) {
     b.Do1();
   });
  }
  void Do2()
  {
   wrapClassB([] (ClassB& b) {
     b.Do2();
   });
  }
};
```

For pre-C++11 you can create [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) instead of lambdas and replace `Fun&&` with `const Fun&`.

Alternatively, if you really want to use macros, you could just define the whole function with the macro:

```
#define VOID_FUNC(name) \
   void name() {\
     Do task x;\
     ClassB b;\
     b.name();\
     Do task y;\
   }
class A
{
  VOID_FUNC(Do1)
  VOID_FUNC(Do2)
};
```

Comment: C++11 added lambda's, but that's just a very convenient way of constructing functors. You could hand-roll them back in 1998.

Comment: Sure you can @MSalters, good point! I've updated the answer slightly